# HorizontalScroll.Value won't programmatically set

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, .net-4.5, scrollbars

I have a Panel with scrollbars, and I frequently want to programmatically scroll a control into view.  For reasons that don't bear mentioning I need my own methods.  Frequently when I try to set

```
MyPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = newScrollValue;
```

the value *simply won't take*.  I can check `MyPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value` immediately after the set, and its value is unchanged.  The values that I'm trying to set are definitely within the Minimum and Maximum range.

Now here's the worst part.  I found out (don't ask how) that if I make the same set twice in a row, that fixes the problem most of the time.  I *really do* have

```
MyPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = newScrollValue;
MyPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = newScrollValue;
```

and that *really does* mostly resolve the issue.  But the issue persists when I'm programmatically scrolling to a control in an extremal corner of MyPanel.  I tried setting the value three times and no dice.

Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?  I mostly want to resolve the lingering issue.

~~~~~~

Edit: the lingering problem turned out to be a simple bug and I fixed it.  The double-set fixes the problem in all cases.  I would still like to know if anyone knows why the first set doesn't take, or if there's a more elegant way to fix the problem than the double-set.

Comment: You scroll by setting the AutoScrollPosition property.  Or by simply using the ScrollToControl() method.

Comment: Double set did work for me on WinForm, thank you, saved my day, scrolled to lower right corner by setting form's both H and V scrollbars .Value to .Maximum (twice each)