# Panel Scroll c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a project that executes a series of assembly commands. The commands are located in a panel(autoscroll = true) and the line that is to be executed each time, is highlighted.

The problem is that if the number of commands is bigger than a number, highlighted text is not shown on screen and user has to manually scroll down the panel to see it.

What i want is to automatically change the scroll focus so user can see the hidden text when this is highlighted. All of the text is arranged in a table using table layout panel.

As you can see below, when the command goes over "0040001C", the text is still highlighted but cannot be shown to the user.
[image]

So, user has to manually scroll down to see the rest of the text that is executing.
Any help??
[image]

Comment: Not using a ListView or a DataGridView is never not a mistake.  It is up to you to set the panel's AutoScrollPosition property.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753978/2902555/) concerning how to scroll a Panel to a specified position.

It creates a new Control at the point you need to make visible, then uses the [Panel.ScrollControlIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to force the panel to scroll to it.

You could use a similar approach here. Whenever a row is highlighted, determine the position of the **top-left corner** of that row within your Panel (how you do this depends on how the table is being drawn). Make it a `System.Drawing.Point` and call it `location`.

Then call

```
location = new Point(location.X - 4, location.Y)
```

Now you can create a new Control at that location (suppose your panel is named panel1)

```
var control = new Control();
control.Location = location;
panel1.Controls.Add(control);
```

Finally, call

```
panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(control)
```

and this should scroll your Panel to the position indicated by `location`.

Don't forget to get rid of the new control by calling

```
panel1.Controls.Remove(control)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'm about to start thinking of what you wrote and i'll let you know if i need any futher help!