# How to find a particular label among many other labels in a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a windows application, in which I have many labels that are placed vertically (top to bottom). A scroll bar is used to see all the labels. I want to include a search/find function in this application. Using this, users can enter a label name in the textbox and click on the search button and the scroll bar should automatically move to the position where that label is located.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

/Manoj.

Comment: Find lable, e.g. `Label found = Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Text == textToFind);` if `found != null` (i.e. the label has been found) get its `Location` and scroll up to this location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the label name and focus the label.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
  {
    if (c.Name == LabelNameinTextBox.Text)
       {
          this.ScrollControlIntoView(c);
          break;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First step you should have List of your labels and use for example TAG  or NAME property like a key to search one labels in list.

When you have found a label you can find Position property that tell you the relative position of label in his parent.

Well, now you have 2 choise:

- Use Win32 Api (more difficult)
- Use trick like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752970/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-panel)

bye